# Display annotations for 3D model object on iOS

Tags: ios, 3d, rendering, scenekit

Please suggest me a solution for displaying annotations (text or images) for 3D model object on iOS.

For details, so far, I'm able to load and display an 3D model object on iOS by following the guide at http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2016/05/10/getting-started-with-modelio/. But I cannot find a way to add annotations, then display them with the 3D model object. I expect the implementation on iOS will be similar with https://sketchfab.com/models/363e92268ff04a6ba8322332004bdaab (on web version).

Thank you for any suggestions and answers.

Comment: I am looking to achieve the exact same thing for my application. Did you succeed in creating this? Can you pls share some sample code on how you did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project the locations of your 3D locations into screen space. Then use the `overlaySKScene` to draw the annotations. This will get the annotations in the right spot, and keep the text a constant size, independent of the distance from the camera to each annotation's location.

Comment: Even i am looking for the same. Is there any sample available for this? I am new to Scenekit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create node with SCNText geometry type. This allows to show text in 3D scene.